# Using a frontend port that is different from the backend port

Tags: marathon, traefik

I have a traefik instance in front of a service. The service runs on port 9000. However I would like port :8000 to proxy the request to this service. Both run in marathon.

I tried using `traefik.port` label however it seems to be assuming that the backend is running on 8000 too when I do this judging from the backend block at :8000/dashboard.

I also tried other solutions such as

`traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefikhost:8000` with no success

The docs are really unclear on this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `traefik.port` to define the port of your backend. In your case it should be `traefik.port=9000`.

By default Traefik will listen on port `80`, as you want it to listen on another port you need to define the address for `entryPoints`, like `--entryPoints='Name:http Address::8000'`, in this example it will listen on port `8000`.

I will give you an example using docker, then you can make a parallel with marathon.

Run Traefik to listen on port `8000`:

```
docker service create \
    --name traefik \
    --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock \
    --network traefik-net \
    --publish 8080:8080 \
    --publish 8000:8000 \
    traefik \
        --entryPoints="Name:http Address::8000" \
        --defaultentrypoints="http" \
        --checknewversion=false \
        --docker \
        --docker.swarmmode \
        --docker.domain=mydomain.com \
        --docker.watch \
        --docker.exposedbydefault=false \
        --web \
        --loglevel=DEBUG
```

Backend listening on port `9000`:

```
docker service create \
    --name myweb \
    --mount type=bind,source=$PWD/httpd.conf,target=/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf \
    --label traefik.port=9000 \
    --label traefik.enable=true \
    --network traefik-net \
    httpd
```

Test it, check Traefik `api`:

```
$ curl -s "http://localhost:8080/api" | jq .
{
  "docker": {
    "backends": {
      "backend-myweb": {
        "servers": {
          "server-myweb-1": {
            "url": "http://10.0.0.5:9000",
            "weight": 0
          }
        },
        "loadBalancer": {
          "method": "wrr"
        }
      }
    },
    "frontends": {
      "frontend-Host-myweb-mydomain-com": {
        "entryPoints": [
          "http"
        ],
        "backend": "backend-myweb",
        "routes": {
          "route-frontend-Host-myweb-mydomain-com": {
            "rule": "Host:myweb.mydomain.com"
          }
        },
        "passHostHeader": true,
        "priority": 0,
        "basicAuth": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now request your backend service:

```
$ curl -H "Host: myweb.mydomain.com" "http://localhost:8000/"
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

Comment: I noticed that you are changing the configuration of traefik itself. Does that mean that I can't control the frontend port of the service itself?

Comment: As you can see `api` output, frontend does not handle port, who does that is Traefik itself. As I know you can't make Traefik listen on ports dynamically In fact that is exactly why we use Traefik, to avoid handle ports dynamically, we define standard ports and it does reverse proxy to ports and ip's created dynamically from backend.